# Trying to add details to a hexigonal base and im having consistency iussues

Tags: modeling, mesh, mirror

im a bit new to blender and im trying to model a hexigonal stand for a prop and i cant get all the details lined up like id like. placing them by hand is obivously not a good way to do it but i tried anyway and it looks really rough, the issue is i want them all to line up like a band surrounding the base of the stand with these raised bits at the corner and i cant get it to look right. [image: what im going for but theres a ton of little things i wanna change to make it more clean]

i tried orientating them with the topdown wireframe view but im certan i messed up somewhhere because everything is just a bit out of whack

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

- Create a plane, in *Edit* mode scale it and move it away form its origin:

[image]

- Give it an *Array* modifier, enable *Object Offset* instead of *Relative Offset*, create an empty at the same position as the plane center, choose it as *Offset*, rotate the empty 60° on Z:

[image]

- Move and edit the mesh in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Extrude it, etc, when you'll be good, apply the modifier and Merge by Distance to merge the vertices:

[image]